# Converting phpbb2 mod to phpbb3

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

Is there a list anywhere on what needs to be done to convert a phpbb2 mod to work with phpbb3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't convert a phpBB2 mod to a phpBB3 mod, you need to rewrite it, you can off-course reuse some code.

Many mods are already upgraded to phpBB3 so maybe you just need to search it on http://phpBB.com